# Create table in dynamoDB with LSI using boto

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I know how to create a table using boto, but I cannot find any online help on creating a table that also includes an LSI. I have searched the boto docs, and the AWS docs. If you have a simple example of how to create such a table, I can take it from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Came across your question in my research to find the same thing. Not sure if you figured this out yet but I thought I'd post my findings for anyone else who may need to know this.

In my situation I needed to be able to query and have results returned based on two different sort keys, 'date' and 'post_id' for a Table that I needed to create called 'Posts' and a Local Secondary Index (LSI) that I wanted to create, called 'PostsByDate'.

Here is my solution below. It's in Python but I'm sure you can figure out what to do with it in your respective language of choice.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000", region_name="us-west-2")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Posts',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'user_id',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'post_id',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        },
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'user_id',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'post_id',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'date',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },

    ],
    LocalSecondaryIndexes=[
        {
            'IndexName': 'PostsByDate',
            'KeySchema': [
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'user_id',
                    'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
                },
                {
                    'AttributeName': 'date',
                    'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
                },
            ],
            'Projection': {
                'ProjectionType': 'ALL'
            }
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10,
        }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

Comment: In this case for PostsByDate filtering, the data must be filtered by providing both user_id and date or only using date will suffice?

Comment: data will be filtered by providing both `user_id` and `date`